# Convert range to string

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

If I run the

```
echo {0..9}
```

command, then I get the following output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Can I somehow put the string `"0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"` into a variable inside `bash` script? I only found a way using `echo`:

```
x=`echo {0..9}`
```

But this method implies the execution of an external program. Is it possible to somehow manage only with `bash`?

Interested, rather than a way to convert a range to a string, but additionally concatenate with a string, for example:

```
datafiles=`echo data{0..9}.txt`
```

Comment: `echo` is a builtin, not an external program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

```
x=`echo {0..9}`
```

doesn't call an external program (`echo` is a built-in) but creates a subshell. If it isn't desired you can use `printf` (a built-in as well) with `-v` option:

```
printf -v x ' %s' {0..9}
x=${x:1} # strip off the leading space
```

or

```
printf -v datafiles ' data%s.txt' {0..9}
datafiles=${datafiles:1}
```

or you may want storing them in an array:

```
datafiles=(data{0..9}.txt)
echo "${datafiles[@]}"
```

This last method will work correctly even if filenames contain whitespace characters:

```
datafiles=(data\ {0..9}\ .txt)
printf '%s\n' "${datafiles[@]}"
```

Comment: is `echo` part of `bash`?

Comment: @AlexeyIsmagilov, sure, run `PAGER='less +/^shell\ builtin\ commands' man bash`

Comment: If you prefer the  online manual, see [Shell Builtin Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html)

Comment: @AlexeyIsmagilov Yes. `echo` is a shell builtin.